# How to remove a particular set of rows from a cell array?

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a cell array with ~6000 rows. Next, I have a vector with a set of row indexes, let's call it `removalIdx`. I would like to create a new cell array that has all of the rows from the original cell array EXCEPT for the rows specified by `removalIdx`. Any ideas on how to do this without reverting to a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example code should answer your question:

```
B = {'hello';'world';'are';'you';'there'}; %# Example cell array
ToRemove = [2; 4]; %# Example indices to remove
Soln = B; %# Create the new cell array
Soln(ToRemove) = []; %# Remove the offending rows
```

Note that:

```
>> Soln

Soln = 

    'hello'
    'are'
    'there'
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I'm amazed it is that easy! I would have assumed that setting rows to [] would keep them in the array as empty cells, but I confirmed that it in fact removes the rows entirely. Thanks again!

Comment: @robguinness It all comes down to `()` versus `{}`. Indexing cell arrays with parentheses `()` works pretty much the same as for numeric matrices. But indexing with `{}` would get the behavior in your comment, ie replace the contents of the cell with an empty matrix. ps Glad I could help.